# Naming standards for our SharePoint columns Internal names

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, site-column

I am working on a new SharePoint site, and we want to create many site columns, so can i know what are the naming standards for site columns' Internal Names inside SharePoint, for example i have those display names:-

1. Car Number
2. Registration Name
3. Date Covered By Customer

so what the internal names for those site columns need to be? if we take the 3rd column as an example should it be defined as `DateCoveredByCustomer` OR `Datecoveredbycustomer` OR `datecoveredbycustomer` or another option?? as based on my test internal names for SharePoint sites column are case sensitive.. any advice?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing with your three examples are all perfectly valid.

DateCoveredByCustomer
Datecoveredbycustomer
datecoveredbycustomer

It's pure semantics.

Personally, I like your first example. Where the first letter of each word is capitalized. I believe some people call that camel case.

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, these three columns should be defined as **Car_x0020_Number**, **Registration_x0020_Name**, **Date_x0020_Covered_x0020_By_x0020_Customer**.

Note: Internal name for SharePoint column is case sensitive.

Internal names are set once at the point of creation; you cannot change them later. Additionally, Internal names encode special characters in your display name including spaces not in the same way as URLs, they use a combination of underscores and x0 numbers to represent the character, for example:

- **x0020 for " "**
- **x003a for ":"**

For more information, please see the **[SharePoint Naming Guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/sharepoint-naming-guidelines#internal-names)**.

**Here is an identical case：**

- [Naming standards for our SharePoint columns Internal names](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/547751/naming-standards-for-our-sharepoint-columns-intern.html)

Answer (score -1):

Some Information as the best practice while creating site column in SharePoint

1. Always create columns without spaces in the name. It becomes useful when trying to use those names from another app like Powershell, power automated and etc.
2. Site column internal names with special characters are get encoded in SharePoint. e.g for " " is replaced with *x0020* OR for ":" replaced with *x003a*
3. Site column internal names cannot be changed once created.
4. Internal names are limited to a specific length of up to 255 Characters in SharePoint Online

Hope this information is useful.

Comment: for your point `Site column names are not case sensitive.` based on my test and using PnP i were able to create 2 site columns with the same internal names but has different case, one site column has its internal name = `Test` while the other has its internal name = `test` so this means the internal names are case sensitive..